# RxAndroidBle on Android - requesting MTU and then reading from connection

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rx-java2, rxandroidble

In [RxAndroidBle](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle), I want to set the MTU and then read a characteristic from the connection.

```
device
    .establishConnection(false)
    .flatMapSingle(conn -> conn.requestMtu(64))
    .flatMapSingle(mtu -> <?>);
```

I'd like to then do a `conn.readCharacteristic`, but I don't have a reference to `conn` after raising the MTU.

I'm fairly new to [RxJava2](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0) so maybe I'm missing something at a conceptual level. Could anybody provide any insight here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that

```
device
    .establishConnection(false)
    .flatMapSingle(conn -> conn.requestMtu(64)
        .flatMap(mtu -> conn.readCharacteristic()))
```